# Where can I change settings/preferences for Files?

Tags: unity, files

I need to change how files are displayed. I want to use a list/details view rather than the icon view. For whatever reason there isn't a traditional File|Settings type menu. How do I change the settings? This is Ubuntu 17.04.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK my mistake. For whatever reason you need to click the application title (in this case "Files") and you get a menu. This is not at all consistent with any other application in Ubuntu/Unity. Pretty bad UX decision.

[image]

Comment: This design choice was implemented by GNOME, they call it **App Menu**: https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/AppMenu